# Update a List<t> object and his properties

Tags: c#, list, algorithm, class, crud

I have a list `MemoryClienti` with items based on the `ClienteModel` class.

The **method** i use to add a new **item** to `MemoryClienti` is:

```
        public bool CreateCliente(ClienteModel model)
    {
        bool empty = !MemoryClienti.Any();
        if (empty)
        {
            ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
            clienteModel.Cognome = model.Cognome;
            clienteModel.Nome = model.Nome;
            clienteModel.Indirizzo = model.Indirizzo;
            clienteModel.IDCliente = StartID;
            MemoryClienti.Add(clienteModel);
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
        }
        else
        {
            int maxID = MemoryClienti.Count;
            ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
            clienteModel.Cognome = model.Cognome;
            clienteModel.Nome = model.Nome;
            clienteModel.Indirizzo = model.Indirizzo;
            clienteModel.IDCliente = maxID;
            MemoryClienti.Add(clienteModel);
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente aggiunto correttamente.");
        }
        return true;
```

This method makes me able to add a new item, count for the number of items in the list, and set the new item's id as the result of the count, so it happpens for every item i add, and it's working.

**Datas** for item's "model" comes from form's **textboxes**:

```
        private void aggiungiClienteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cognomeTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uno o più campi sono vuoti");
        }
        else if (nomeTextBox.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uno o più campi sono vuoti");
        }
        else if (indirizzoTextbox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uno o più campi sono vuoti");
        }
        else
        {
            clienteModel.Cognome = cognomeTextBox.Text;
            clienteModel.Nome = nomeTextBox.Text;
            clienteModel.Indirizzo = indirizzoTextbox.Text;
            dbMemoryManager.CreateCliente(clienteModel);
            cognomeTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            nomeTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
            indirizzoTextbox.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

My **class** is:

```
    public class ClienteModel
{
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }

}
```

The problem is: *how can i update **one** of those items using textboxes without changing the id?*

Comment: The question is how do you want to identify an existing client? By last name/first name? by ID? You could have an ID textbox. When an optional ID is entered, search for an existing client and update it.

Comment: Yeah the best way could be via identifying via id, but i don't know how to; maybe linq, but i can only find one property (am i wrong?) and i don't really know how to update it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution.  You don't specify what kind of textboxes you are using.  I'm assuming it's Windows Forms.

I modified your ClienteModel so that it looks like this:

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    private static int _currentId = 0;
    public int IDCliente { get; set; } = _currentId++;
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Indirizzo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Nome;
    }
}
```

Note that it manages the `IDCliente` field now and that it has a `ToString` member (you can set this to whatever string you want).  You may want to show the `IDCliente` field in a read-only textbox on your form.

Then I created a simple Windows Forms form that has your three text boxes, a ListBox named `ModelsListBox` and two buttons `AddButton` (caption: "Add") and `UpdateButton` ("Update").

In the form class I created a little validation method (since I use it in two places).  Note that you will only get one MessageBox even if you have multiple errors:

```
private bool ValidateFields()
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var tb in new[] {cognomeTextBox, nomeTextBox, indirizzoTextbox})
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
        {
            errors.Add($"{tb.Name} must not be empty");
        }
    }

    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors), "Errors", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    //otherwise
    return true;
}
```

Then I added three event handlers (wiring them up in the normal fashion from within the designer).  The first is when the Add button is pressed:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateFields())
    {
        return;
    }

    var model = new ClienteModel
    {
        Cognome = cognomeTextBox.Text,
        Nome = nomeTextBox.Text,
        Indirizzo = indirizzoTextbox.Text,
    };
    ModelsListBox.Items.Add(model);
}
```

It creates a new `ClienteModel` and adds it to the listbox (assuming validation passes).

Then, I created a handler that updates the text boxes whenever the selection in the listbox changes:

```
private void ModelsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ModelsListBox.SelectedItem is ClienteModel model)
    {
        cognomeTextBox.Text = model.Cognome;
        nomeTextBox.Text = model.Nome;
        indirizzoTextbox.Text = model.Indirizzo;
    }
}
```

and finally, an update button handler:

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidateFields())
    {
        return;
    }
    if (ModelsListBox.SelectedItem is ClienteModel model)
    {
        model.Cognome = cognomeTextBox.Text;
        model.Nome = nomeTextBox.Text;
        model.Indirizzo = indirizzoTextbox.Text;
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect.  You should disable the Update button until a selection is made (and maybe enable only after a change is made in the text box).

More importantly, the string shown in the listbox for an item is based on the results of a call to `ClienteModel.ToString` made when the item is first added to the list.  If you change the value of a field that is used to compute `.ToString`, the listbox doesn't update.  There are a few ways around this (findable on Stack Overflow), but I thought this would be enough to get you started.

Comment: I solved by myself but i checked your work and it works, i appreciate sooo much your effort and the time you spent for me, really.